# How to add custom text on both sides of a result of a select query

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am trying to create an SQL which adds custom text on both sides of the result of an SQL query in Postgres. I have many site domains stored in a database and I would like to copy them into an HTML file with the domain names inside an iframe. So I would like the query to return my domains within `<iframe></iframe>` tag. I found the following from the Postgresql documentation.

```
SELECT textcat(textcat(first_name,text ' '),last_name) from table;
```

But what I am looking for is different. My simple select SQL would be

```
select site_domain from site where status = "active".
```

Is there any function that allows me to append custom text on both sides of my result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean something like this?

```
   select '<iframe>'|| site_domain||'</iframe>' 
    from site where status = "active"
```

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to Mark's answer would be to use the `CONCAT` function:

```
SELECT CONCAT('<iframe>', site_domain, '</iframe>') AS site_domain
FROM site
WHERE status = 'active'
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try:

```
SELECT textcat(textcat('<iframe>',site_domain),'</iframe>')
from site 
where status = 'active';
```